# How do I display a notification within an anchor in my controller using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I am trying to show a notification from within an anchor

in my controller I have this array that is saved into

```
$data['table_data'];
```

that is then displayed in my view by calling `$data_table`

```
$this->table->add_row($cellCl,$cellT,$cellE,$cellA,$cellTR,  
anchor('notifications/print/'.$reg->id,'.',array('class'=>'img1')).'   
'.anchor('notifications/write/'.$reg->id,'.',array('class'=>'img2')).' 
'.anchor('notifications/read/'.$reg->id,'.',array('class'=>'notification'))  
);
```

and I want to show something like what is in the snippet inside the anchor that shows the notification image (rather than showing the notification image).

```css
a.fa-globe {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span.fa-comment {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  top: -4px;
  color: red;
  right: -4px;
}
span.num {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.3em;
  top: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a class="fa fa-globe">
  <span class="fa fa-comment"></span>
  <span class="num">2</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to the `anchor` function is usually the text that shows up in between the `<a>` element.

EG

```
echo anchor('url', 'Text'); // <a href="url">Text</a>
```

But this isn't limited to just text content. You can put in HTML as well.

EG

```
echo anchor('url', '<span style="color: red">Test</span>');
// <a href="url"><span style="color: red">Test</span></a>
```

So you could add `<span class="fa fa-comment"></span><span class="num">2</span>` to the second parameter of `anchor` to have it render the HTML.